# Error Code: 1048, SQL State: 23000 Column 'colegiado_id' cannot be null

Tags: mysql

this error
"[Error Code: 1048, SQL State: 23000]  Column 'colegiado_id' cannot be null"

appears when I try to run the code below, direct in the mysql:

```
start transaction;
INSERT INTO EspecialistasColegiados (colegiado_id, especialista_id) (
    select
        col.id as colegiado_id,
        esp.id as especialista_id

    from Especialista esp
        inner join importacao imp ON imp.idimportacao = esp.id
        left join Colegiado col ON col.nome like concat('%',imp.CURSOS,'%')
    );
rollback;
```

Comment: Could you add the table definitions and some sample data and the expected output to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You missed to ask a question.

The error is quite obvious though: One of the values in "col.id" from "Especialista" is null, and this is not configured as allowed for "calegiado_id".